# Arborescent structure in application.properties

Tags: spring-boot

I am reading/practicing a [security management tutorial](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/the-resource-server-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-iii) with Spring-boot. I noticed that I could customize the application by using either a file named `application.properties` or a file named `application.yml`depending on the syntax I prefer.

Then I reached a point in the tutorial where it is asked to put this piece of information in `application.yml` :

```
security:
  sessions: NEVER
```

**Problem** : this piece of configuration is obviously arborescent and fits well in `application.yml` but what would be the equivalent in `application.properties` which, AFAIK, like every `.properties` files is not meant to store arborescent data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where YAML uses new lines and indentation, a properties file uses `.` separators. The equivalent configuration in `application.properties` would be:

```
security.sessions=NEVER
```